# Refer Master Detail or Lookup via external key in POST

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, rest, soap, bulk-api

I am using this code to populate master detail

```
Terminal__c testTerm = new Terminal__c();

testTerm.Terminal_Name_External__c= 'TEST Terminal';
testTerm.Name = 'TEST Terminal';
testTerm.Port_Code__r = new Port__c(Port_Code_External_ID__c = 'ESALG');

upsert testTerm;

System.debug(testTerm.Id);
```

Now I want to use the same in Bulk api integration
how to refer masterdetail?

I am getting error in

> ```
> {
> "Terminal_Name_External__c":"TEST Terminal",
> "Name":"TEST Terminal",
> "Port_Code__r.Port_Code_External_ID__c":"ESALG",
> }
> ```
>
> Invalid "Port_Code__r.Port_Code_External_ID__c"

Answer (score 1):

With the direct Apex upsert you are [Relating Records by Using an External ID](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_nested_object.htm). That has a syntax specific to Apex.

For the Bulk API the syntax for [Relationship Fields in Records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_xml_rel_fields.htm) is different.

Try something like:

> "RelationshipName" : { "IndexedFieldName" : "rwilliams@salesforcesample.com" }

E.g.

```
{
"Terminal_Name_External__c":"TEST Terminal",
"Name":"TEST Terminal",
"Port_Code__r" : {"Port_Code_External_ID__c" : "ESALG"}
}
```